# Getting error on direct http tx call to stellar core

Tags: stellar-core

I am trying to send a transaction via http call without Horizon. 
Here is the tx information

```
http://localhost:11626/tx?blob=QUFBQUFINHhLV3NXalNsUWRHeFM0QWNWdmdDUGlzenZReWVabjQwWGdlQVVrNmtlQUFBQVpBQUFBQUFBQUFBQkFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUJBQUFBQVFBQUFBQitNU2xyRm8wcFVIUnNVdUFIRmI0QWo0ck03ME1ubVorTkY0SGdGSk9wSGdBQUFBQUFBQUFBMDEzQllJallsQ0g2MWxSaU96TDRpS3ZBVitJQXNUa2dLQklIa0tsa2dad0FBQUFBZHpXVUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQkZKT3BIZ0FBQUVDY1M2NGJPL1RGM1NESndKY2o4QmtaTFcxTFdKUWJTcVY3RUk2K3YxbzFaRlY2bzYwOUI5S1FXU0txb3lIRmlVSGJHdmJqZG5NTUo0YU1mbzAyYlk4Tw==
```

but I am getting error:

```
{"exception": "bad value of type in PublicKey"}
```

I tried to debug the code. It is throwing this error in this line `xdr::xdr_from_opaque(binBlob, envelope);` which I am not sure what it is.

TIA!

---

Edit:

I am using custom network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to debug it, my samples are in python, but use whatever suits you.

**View your TX in the stellar laboratory**

Base64 decode your blob:

```
>>> from base64 import b64decode
>>> b64decode('QUFBQUFINHhLV3NXalNsUWRHeFM0QWNWdmdDUGlzenZReWVabjQwWGdlQVVrNmtlQUFBQVpBQUFBQUFBQUFBQkFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUJBQUFBQVFBQUFBQitNU2xyRm8wcFVIUnNVdUFIRmI0QWo0ck03ME1ubVorTkY0SGdGSk9wSGdBQUFBQUFBQUFBMDEzQllJallsQ0g2MWxSaU96TDRpS3ZBVitJQXNUa2dLQklIa0tsa2dad0FBQUFBZHpXVUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQkZKT3BIZ0FBQUVDY1M2NGJPL1RGM1NESndKY2o4QmtaTFcxTFdKUWJTcVY3RUk2K3YxbzFaRlY2bzYwOUI5S1FXU0txb3lIRmlVSGJHdmJqZG5NTUo0YU1mbzAyYlk4Tw==')
b'AAAAAH4xKWsWjSlQdGxS4AcVvgCPiszvQyeZn40XgeAUk6keAAAAZAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAB+MSlrFo0pUHRsUuAHFb4Aj4rM70MnmZ+NF4HgFJOpHgAAAAAAAAAA013BYIjYlCH61lRiOzL4iKvAV+IAsTkgKBIHkKlkgZwAAAAAdzWUAAAAAAAAAAABFJOpHgAAAECcS64bO/TF3SDJwJcj8BkZLW1LWJQbSqV7EI6+v1o1ZFV6o609B9KQWSKqoyHFiUHbGvbjdnMMJ4aMfo02bY8O'
```

Take it [to the lab](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAH4xKWsWjSlQdGxS4AcVvgCPiszvQyeZn40XgeAUk6keAAAAZAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAB%2BMSlrFo0pUHRsUuAHFb4Aj4rM70MnmZ%2BNF4HgFJOpHgAAAAAAAAAA013BYIjYlCH61lRiOzL4iKvAV%2BIAsTkgKBIHkKlkgZwAAAAAdzWUAAAAAAAAAAABFJOpHgAAAECcS64bO%2FTF3SDJwJcj8BkZLW1LWJQbSqV7EI6%2Bv1o1ZFV6o609B9KQWSKqoyHFiUHbGvbjdnMMJ4aMfo02bY8O&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test).

Note that there is a problem with the signature.

**Fire your TX to horizon to get a better error**

```
>>> from stellar_base.builder import Builder
>>> b = Builder(address='GB7DCKLLC2GSSUDUNRJOABYVXYAI7CWM55BSPGM7RULYDYAUSOUR4WA4')
>>> b.import_from_xdr('AAAAAH4xKWsWjSlQdGxS4AcVvgCPiszvQyeZn40XgeAUk6keAAAAZAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAB+MSlrFo0pUHRsUuAHFb4Aj4rM70MnmZ+NF4HgFJOpHgAAAAAAAAAA013BYIjYlCH61lRiOzL4iKvAV+IAsTkgKBIHkKlkgZwAAAAAdzWUAAAAAAAAAAABFJOpHgAAAECcS64bO/TF3SDJwJcj8BkZLW1LWJQbSqV7EI6+v1o1ZFV6o609B9KQWSKqoyHFiUHbGvbjdnMMJ4aMfo02bY8O')
>>> b.submit()
```

Check the output - the problem in question is `'result_codes': {'transaction': 'tx_bad_seq'}` - you'd run into this once you fixed your signature problem - bumb up the sequence.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry forgot to mention in my question that, I am using custom network not test or public. I think you have checked in the test/public network that is why you've got `bad_seq` error. For me every thing seems to be correct in laboratory. but still throwing error when called stellar-core. :(

Comment: Closing this question as I figured out this happened because of build problem. and accepting this answer as well.